# Python class variable weird scope visibility rules

Tags: python, class, variables, scope, visibility

```
$ cat func.py 
a = 'global'
def myfunc():
  a = 'myfunc'
  class myclass:
    print('myclass a =', a)
#    a = 'myclass'
myfunc()
$ python3.8 func.py 
myclass a = myfunc

$ cat func.py 
a = 'global'
def myfunc():
  a = 'myfunc'
  class myclass:
    print('myclass a =', a)
    a = 'myclass'
myfunc()
$ python3.8 func.py 
myclass a = global
```

Which are the variable visibility rules applicable to the a attribute of myclass and how do they explain these results?
References to documentation welcome, but not required.

I have been asked to explain how does [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules) not answer my question here. The answer is ridiculously simple: that question and its answers do not address the case of a nested class, with one exception, which certainly does not explain the weird "global" output in my example, which directly contradicts the rule that the variable should be resolved to the closest nesting scope.

Comment: if you put a class in a function it works as a decorator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: There is no `a` attribute of `myclass`. It is a closure variable.

Comment: @mousetail I believe that classes cannot define closures. Your comment was helpful because it made me read about closures.

Comment: @Flow Decorators are based on closures, and I believe that classes do not define closures. Your comment was helpful because it made me read about decorators.

Comment: @buran Your link is very helpful. It is the first coherent presentation on the topic that I found. However, classes are not clearly addressed. I believe that classes have not been designed for this scope imbrication.

Comment: @DoruGeorgescu Happy to help, I do not know that as well so thanks for informing me

Comment: @DoruGeorgescu Classes can define closures themselves. In fact classes are really just a type of closure.

Comment: @mousetail Function attributes can define closures because they are functions. If you can provide an example where classes themselves define closures, I'd be most interested to see it.

Answer (score 0):

[4.2.2. Resolution of names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names)

> Class definition blocks and arguments to exec() and eval() are special
> in the context of name resolution. A class definition is an executable
> statement that may use and define names. These references follow the
> normal rules for name resolution with an exception that unbound local
> variables are looked up in the global namespace.

In the first example, `a` follows the normal rules for name resolution and resolves to the nearest enclosing scope, which is `myfunc()`.

In the second example, `a` is local, because it is assigned within the class scope with no `nonlocal` or `global` declaration, and it is unbound because it is resolved before the assignment. So it resolves to the global scope.

This is weird.